# How to use the ListCollectionView GroupBySelector property?

Tags: wpf, grouping

In WPF, you can easily group lists of items as explained [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/). Though, sometimes you need more advanced grouping logic. Reading the documentation it seems there are tools for that purpose. However, this feature seems to be rarely used, and as of writing I get no hits when googling.

Please be the first to show some tested sample code, demonstrating how to use the [ListCollectionView.GroupBySelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.groupbyselector(v=vs.110).aspx) property and its 
[GroupDescriptionSelectorCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.groupdescriptionselectorcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) callback!

Here's a start:

```
MyView = new ListCollectionView(myItems)
{
    GroupBySelector = MySelector
};

private static GroupDescription MySelector(CollectionViewGroup group, int level)
{
    // TODO: Not sure what to return here!
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GroupBySelector` property to select a `GroupDescription`, i.e. what property you want to group by, based on your custom logic at a particular level.

In the sample code you linked to, you could for example have used this property to group the `List<User>` by the `Sex` property:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<User> items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Sex = SexType.Male });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Sex = SexType.Female });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13, Sex = SexType.Male });
        lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

        ListCollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource) as ListCollectionView;
        view.GroupBySelector = MySelector;
    }

    private static GroupDescription MySelector(CollectionViewGroup group, int level)
    {
        if(level == 0)
            return new PropertyGroupDescription("Sex");

        return null;
    }
}
```

Or/and by another property at another level, e.g.:

```
private static GroupDescription MySelector(CollectionViewGroup group, int level)
{
    if (level == 0)
        return new PropertyGroupDescription("Sex");
    if (level == 1)
        return new PropertyGroupDescription("Age");

    return null;
}
```

Of course you could accomplish the same results by adding another `PropertyGroupDescription` to the `GroupDescriptions` collection of the `CollectionView` in this particular and very basic example, but the point is that you can use this property whenever you need to dynamically add `GroupDescriptions` at various levels based on some custom logic of yours.

Comment: Returning `null` seems important (non-null keeps the loop going). I guess that the level count should be determined beforehand? Otherwise it would be nice to be able to build a dynamic tree structure...